Gradient of a non-differentiable function
I am trying to solve the IVP
$$
y' = f(x, y), \quad y(0) = 0.
$$
When $f(x, y) = \sqrt{|y|}$, there is a non-unique solution to the differential equation. On the other hand, when $f(x, y) = \frac{1}{y^2}$, the function has a unique solution, although the value on the $x$-axis tends to infinity. My idea is to find the intrinsic property of the function responsible for its uniqueness.
So, my question is: Let $f(x, y)$ be a non-differentiable function, with the $x$-axis being the set of points of non-differentiability. What can be said about the gradients at those points? (In the first case, the gradient is undefined, and in the second case, it tends to infinity.)
I want to understand the behavior of the integral curve, thinking of it as the stationary flow.
